# Should previously asked/answered questions get migrated or cross searched between SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

I can't help but notice that many new SE and Beta sites have been popping up all over the place in the past couple of years.  There seems to be a retro overlap on some to the older questions SO houses (meaning the question more resembles that of a Programmers, SU, SF, etc question).  From an asker's stand point on SO, due dilligence comes in the form making sure the question was not asked previously (becoming quite a challenge these days), and I happen to notice many of the older questions, some protected, appear to be in that type of situation.  There have been a few times I have seen duplicate questions across SE sites (wish I could remember what they were!).

**My question is that should these questions be retroactively be migrated?  If not, what is the value of retaining these type of questions for the orginating SE that it was asked on?**

Realizing what kind of impact retroactive migration could have, **a possible feature proposal could be an additional flag that indicates an appropriate SE sites the question could be searchable on.**  Yet again, I don't know the cost/benifit side for what looks like a relatively narrow proposal.  Just a thought.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) is an example question that be could to be searchable on Programmers, but not migrated.  (could fall under quality assurance in Programmers faq page)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749229/direct-x-in-c-game-programming) is an example question that could be migrated or searchable in Game Developers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213119/how-do-i-know-whether-my-display-driver-supports-directx-or-not) is an example question that I flagged to be migrated to SU, but could be searchable in SO or Game Developers.

**EDIT:**

I know theres several questions out there to the flavor of "Should Previous Questions Be Migrated?"  Just wanted to use the subject as a segway to the proposal.

Comment: The "What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?" is horribly off topic for P.SE. [Quality assurance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance)? What's the connection?

Comment: Ok, gave it a second look and it is a bit of a stretch.  I was in a hurry.  But doesn't mean that there isn't some overlap of interest the question has yielded in content.  On the other hand, this could be a fine example of a bad flag where a mod would choose, like any other flag, to let it proceed with the association or not.  The main question to keep in mind; should the content of that particular question be searchable from programmers with an appropriately given flag?

Comment: What would be the benefit? There's an overlap of interest with every software development related site out there, why would we want anything to do with this particular question? If it was on a source that is tuned to accommodate poll like questions, like Quora, or a quality general reference site, we would probably refer to it a lot from Programmers. But as is, I'd prefer SOpedians delete it and we can forget about it asap, there's too much populist voting in it. Read the Dragon Book, build my own little compiler, it's _not_ a book every programmer should read.

Comment: The only book recommendation questions we allow on P.SE, are questions on canonical books on very specific topics. Those questions and their answers are awesome, they are concentrated on a topic and answerers are encourage to tell us _exactly why_ they recommend the book - or else answers are down voted to oblivion. If that question was searchable from P.SE, it would probably appear before all those questions. I don't want that.

Comment: So, what I am getting is that "some" overlap doesn't mean it should be searchable from another SE site.  But I would guess that the Direct X question (3rd example) posted on SO would be at least a 90% overlap with SU? Heres a post very similar to that question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/44952/how-can-i-determine-the-highest-gpu-supported-directx-version

Comment: I _think_ the best option in this case would be to migrate the SO question to SU, and close it as a duplicate of the one you found - or another one that overlaps even more, it's a trivial question I'm pretty sure it has been asked on SU in various forms. But treat that as a guess, I'm a P.SE guy, don't know much about what the other communities would want.

Comment: It is good to point out the end result of the flagging would depend on the assumptions made by the deciding mod on what other communities are interested in.  Still, the 2nd example is kind of a toss up whether it should be migrated, but could be searchable content on both SO and GD.SE.  You know, a one-to-many relationship. One hosting site many searchable sites.  One flag per searchable site.